# Same spreadsheet structure and formulas but different data

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-template

I have a dozen spreadsheets with **identical structure and formulas**, essentially tables, **only the data differ**, say one spreadsheet per country.

For example there is a spreadsheet to manage the US employees, another for the UK employees, and another for the Canada employees.
They are exactly the same except that each will store a different set of employees.
The spreadsheets act both as a database to store data and a user-interface to interact with data.

Each change (updating or adding a formula, updating some drop-downs values, changing style...) has to be **replicated** in all the spreadsheets which is time consuming and error-prone.
As an example I could change the formula to compute the seniority of each employee by editing the 3 spreadsheets.

I was wondering if there was a reasonably simple way to **avoid duplicating the common parts**, only having different data.

I'd like to avoid a full-blown development with plenty of VBA code, a complete database, some user input forms... but if really necessary I can write some VBA and build some database to fill in the blanks if there is no out-of-the-box solution.

With a full-blown development I would do something like:

- store all the employees in a single SQL database table
- develop a single spreadsheet
- when opening the spreadsheet ask the user to choose a country to only load the this country's employees
- save the data changes to the database

Comment: @invisible-downvoter Is is a duplicate? If so please reference the other question. Thanks. :)

Comment: I'm not one of the downvoters, but I can see why you got downvoted: your question isn't that specific, and doesn't tell us anything about the nature of the changes you want replicated. Are they to structure? Or changes to constants used by formulas? Can you elaborate further?

Comment: @jeffreyweir Thanks for the feedback, I've been more "specific" concerning the changes, but it can be any change. :)

Comment: Do these spreadsheets get distributed to other people, and then later sent back to you for consolidation? Or are they just for your own use?

Comment: A simple change would be to have one calculation / dispkay sheet with a choose function bringing the relevant data in from a drop down where you select the country you want to look at.

Comment: @SolarMike I think the OP's question is more along the lines of version control

Comment: @jeffreyweir then the suggestion I made would also help that as only one sheet has calculations...

Comment: @SolarMike   The OP needs to propagate changes of any nature including formatting and structural changes to a dozen spreadsheet templates, to keep them consistent.

Comment: @jeffreyweir no, the OP could have one sheet and call in any one of the data sets as needed which also means consistency...

Comment: @SolarMike  Each change (updating or adding a formula, updating some drop-downs values, changing style...) has to be replicated **in all** the spreadsheets.

Comment: @jeffreyweir you seem to be stuck on the idea of the OP MUST have 12 spreadsheets - I think otherwise but never mind...

Comment: @SolarMike They're the OP's requirements, not mine.

Comment: @jeffreyweir so if you read the OP's 3rd paragrah :" I was wondering if there was a reasonably simple way to avoid duplicating the common parts, only having different data. " The Op is asking for a simple way to reduce duplication which I have offered - all you have offered is to try and keep track of changes....

Comment: @SolarMike Yup, that is all I have offered. I'll leave it to the OP to confirm whether that is what they require.

Comment: @both If making a full-blown development I would indeed use only one spreadsheet with a database storing the varying data with the user choosing a context/country when opening the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

If you're effectively talking about an efficient way to handle version control so that input sheets that have previously been distributed to users match a master template, then I'm afraid there is no out-of-the-box solution.

I use something along the lines of http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/building-version-control-in-excel/ to force users to download the latest template should they be using an older one.

In addition, I also place a big note at the top to prompt users to download a new template each time, rather than recycle an old one, because if a user didn't enable macros the automatic download of the latest template won't kick in.

[image]

Note that the above screenshot shows a form that I've built in Excel's grid itself, using **shudder** merged cells. (i.e. It is not a userform)

If the templates need to preserve user-submitted data that isn't held centrally, then you're probably going to need to develop an add-in along the lines of what the authors do in the book Professional Excel Development.

Comment: I had users using a charting template and as they opened the template it itself checked for an updated version of itself - which if it found, it would then download, then continue to plot and chart the data : all that was needed was a cell with a datecode and the macro did the rest... And, yes, it had internet access as that was how the latest data was brought in...

Comment: Thanks but my main issue is not temporal (new versions of a spreadsheet) but spatial (multiple variations of the same spreadsheet). :) I was considering Excel templates (XLT) but I don't think they are made for this use-case. Anyway +1 :)

Comment: @Pragmateek I don't quite follow the difference between your 'temporal' and 'spatial' examples. In either case, don't you effectively need to propagate changes to one across all? Or is it more a case of extracting data from slightly different workbooks (in which case I'd recommend you check out PowerQuery, which is built in to Excel 2016 and available as a free MS add-in for 2010/2013)?

Comment: I will add a more explicit description of my use-case in my original question. As for PowerQuery not sure it could help, but anyway we are stuck with Office 2010. :)

Comment: Ok. Given that the *spreadsheets act both as a database to store data and a user-interface to interact with data*, then I think the only way to do this is to go down the full-blown route, so that a) the data doesn't sit in workbooks that you will have to update and b) you can update templates using the approach above. Maybe Excel isn't the best vehicle for this. I don't suppose you have Sharepoint? I understand that could help by letting you use a more Excel-app based in-browser approach to capture data. But I'm out of my depth there.

Comment: @jeffreyweir This is what I feared. We don't have Sharepoin either. So as of now I will simply replicate the changes, as they should be the last, and if later new ones come I'll consider refactoring the whole thing into a cleaner application and architecture.